# Back-end can't receive any request when there's no internet

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Im having a problem with my system idk if it's in the backend(nodejs) or frontend(react). Both are running in my computer locally but when i tried to turn off the internet, my backend can't receive any request from my front end anymore.

I tried to request through postman while the internet is off and it responded

Comment: Since using Postman to send the request works, my guess is that the backend isn't at fault. Other than that, it's hard to tell anything else because you haven't provided any code or examples from your application, particularly relating to the fetch being made in the front end. It would also help to know how you are running your React project, be it live server or a script like`npm start` provided by `create-react-app`. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.